# Can I convert raster to shape by specify class?

Tags: arcobjects, c#

I use the method "IMultivariateOp.MLClassify",so I get many class such as the figure below,
[image: Convert]

can you give some code in C# to convert each of them to shape?

one more question, why I just get the first three item?

here is my test code:

```cs
IRasterLayer rl = (IRasterLayer)map_con.get_Layer(0); 
IRaster r = rl.Raster; 
IRasterBandCollection rbc = r as IRasterBandCollection; 
for(int rc = 0; rc < rbc.Count; rc++) 
{ 
   IRasterBand rb = rbc.Item(rc); 
   ITable t = rb.AttributeTable; 
   int fileIndex = t.Fields.FindField("Count"); 
   for(int i = 0; i < t.Fields.FieldCount; i++) 
    { 
     writer.WriteLine(t.GetRow(i + 1).get_Value(fileIndex)); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You first need to iterate over your raster table and select each unique class, then you may use the [RasterDataToPolygonFeatureData](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/java/gp_toolref/spatial_analyst_tools/rasterdatatopolygonfeaturedata.htm) snippet to convert to shapefile (this is in VB, however it may be converted using [developerFusion](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/) site).

Comment: Thanks for your response and I follow your advise,but can you just give some detail about how to get each unique class,and one more question, why I just get the first three item?I just added my code above...

Comment: The count of the IRasterBandCollection is "1" when debuging,but I can not get the last 6 items,